# User identification using ssl only

Tags: authentication, ssl, ibm-mq

I configured SSL security for my IBM MQ. I disabled user identification using

```
ALTER AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)

REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

I set up an MCA user id on the respective channel, so after the connection is established this user is used for any further actions. I checked out IBM MQ documentation and found that there exist two ways of user identification (using system user or LDAP). Now I want to turn on user identification, but instead of system user or LDAP I want to use SSL certificate only. I don't want either to hand on user or password nor to configure LDAP.

My question is, is it possible to use SSL security not only for connection establishing (authentication), but also for user identification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use the certificate Distinguished Name details to map a user into the MCAUSER that the running channel uses. To do this you would use the CHLAUTH feature.

Make sure it is enabled:-

```
DISPLAY QMGR CHLAUTH
```

and if it isn't, enable it with the following command:-

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(ENABLED)
```

To map from an SSL certificate to an MCAUSER, you would create a CHLAUTH rule something like this:-

```
SET CHLAUTH(APP1.SSL.SVRCONN) TYPE(SSLPEERMAP) SSLPEER('CN=Morag,O=MQGem') MCAUSER('hughson')
```

where APP1.SSL.SVRCONN was my channel name, the string in the SSLPEER field was the Subject's DN from my certificate, and 'hughson' is the value I want to see the running channel use in its MCAUSER when a connection from this certificate comes into this channel.

This sort of rule is often combined with a [backstop rule](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/websphere_mq_chlauth_the_back_stop_rule), and/or a rubbish user id in the MCAUSER. Thus if you don't match a CHLAUTH rule that fills in a suitable MCAUSER then the channel won't run.